# Map Region Initial position and zoom not working in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm setting the default map zoom via the **'Initial Position and Zoom'** configuration in the Attributes tab on the Region configuration panel with the following code:

```sql
    select to_number(:P17_GPS_LATITUDE) as LAT,
    to_number(:P17_GPS_LONGITUDE) as LON,
    15 as ZOOM
    from DUAL
```

This is working correctly the first time, but stops working when I enter this page again until I log off the application and log in again.
I've looked at what could be the problem and found that a part of the script that loads the map is different the first time compared to when it loads after that.
The first time it loads this is what I can find (I'm only leaving the parts that are different between loads):

```js
    apex.jQuery('#localitzacioMapa_map_region')
    .spatialMap({ 
        "regionStaticId": "localitzacioMapa", 
        "resetMapPosition": true, 
        "initPosition": { "basedOnFeatures": false, "lon": 1.8246315941379123, "lat": 45.97590926950204, "zoom": 15, "getFromBrowser": false }
    })
```

After that, it will load like the following code and it won't be fixed until i log off and log in again:

```js
    apex.jQuery('#localitzacioMapa_map_region')
    .spatialMap({ 
        "regionStaticId": "localitzacioMapa", 
        "initPosition": { "basedOnFeatures": false, "zoom": 0, "getFromBrowser": false }
    })
```

My issue is that the **LAT** and **LON** values are not being passed correctly and the **zoom** value resets to 0 for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your items `P17_GPS_LATITUDE` and `P17_GPS_LONGITUDE` are not set to your default values correctly. Note that the `default` entry in the item attributes only sets the client-side default and is probably useless in your case. You need to set up the `source` entry correctly.

Now you should know that it is important to know, **when** APEX calculates something. Depending on the position of your items, it could happen that for a fresh session, where your items are initially empty, first your map gets rendered and *then* your items are set to the default values.

To be absolutely sure that your items have the correct default value, when the map gets rendered, use a `Before Header` process to check if your items are null, and then set them, like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was some days out of the office. I've checked and the source is correctly set in the map layer as I can see the point marked in the map, so I assume the values are not null when the map renders, but the problem still persists. The location & zoom options are only used the first time I open a map in that session.